# Interaction with readonly attributes in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, readonly

I am trying to automate tests for a website that uses lots of ready-only webElements:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="enter text here" name="badgeNo">
```

I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 
 Cannot click on element (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace 
                          information)
```

Is there a way around this, without changing the html?

Comment: You need to make sure the element is visible before trying to operate on it.

Comment: Actions such as `SendKeys()` and `Click()` cannot be performed on readonly elements, although I would have expected to see an `InvalidElementStateException` instead. What are the values for the enabled and displayed properties?